# how to use jQuery to slide on and off a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slide

i have this div :

```
<div class="services_box">

            <div class="BOX_A">
                <img src="css/images/icon1.png" alt="" />
                <h1>Services title goes here</h1>
                <p>Aenean ultrices purus porttitor oro er risus molestie vestibulum. Morbi et nus metus justo, semper eget condimentum vitae, con varius ut sapien. Ut egestas enim non ante sagittis eget egestas tellus consequat.</p>
                <div class="servicesbutton"> <a href="#" title=""></a> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="BOX_B" **style="display:none;"**>
                <img src="css/images/icon1.png" alt="" />
                <h1>Services title goes here</h1>
                <p>Aenean ultrices purus porttitor oro er risus molestie vestibulum. Morbi et nus metus justo, semper eget condimentum vitae, con varius ut sapien. Ut egestas enim non ante sagittis eget egestas tellus consequat.</p>
                <div class="servicesbutton"> <a href="#" title=""></a> </div>
            </div>      

        </div>
```

how can i make the hidden div slide in and out on click on the link, using jQuery / js  ?

Comment: Please search here before posting a question; a lot of similar questions are  already here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? **Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/StJ9e/1/

```
$('div.BOX_A h1, div.BOX_B h1').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.slide').slideToggle();
});
```

Or if your looking for an accordion type effect:

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bK4rN/2/

```
var $last = jQuery('.BOX_A .slide');

$('.services_box').delegate('div > h1', 'click', function() {
    $last.slideUp();
    $last = $(this).siblings('.slide');
    $last.stop(true, true).slideDown();
});
```

---

**Edit**: in response to comment

> I need something like this : jsfiddle.net/hJwqs/1 ... but i need only one this to change, not all.

Change your code to:

```
$("div.BOX_A a").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.services_box').find('div.BOX_A').slideToggle();
});
```

### **Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/3KBug/

*or for a styled one: http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/cuEUG/*

Comment: no . I need to have only one div visible, not both .
the second div should rollover the first one .

Comment: i need something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/hJwqs/1/   ... but i need only one this to change, not all .

Comment: WOW YEAH ! something like this yeah ! thanks a lot Gary ! nice short code :)

Comment: No problem. Please remember to click on the "tick" next to this answer to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: and with a fixed div height the exchange is done without any div flickers . cheers ! :) and thanks again.

Comment: I come back with a question, how about if the hidden div is to appear on hover ? seems like .hover(function instead of .click(function , is putting the toggle into a loop .. how to make it run only once ?

Comment: let's say again, like an image caption !

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.fadeIn()` method to make it appear and `.fadeOut()` to dissapear, also you can use the

```
.toggle() method, you can search more on google, here are the docs anyway:
```

toggle: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

fadein: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

fadeout: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you mean is it something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.BOX_A").bind("click", function() { $(this).slideToggle(); });
    $("div.BOX_B").bind("click", function() { $(this).slideToggle(); });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AFLUp/

If you clarify what exactly should be seen/hidden etc I can modify the code to help you :)

Comment: let's say more link this :
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/AFLUp/4/)

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".linka").bind("click", function() { $(".BOXA").slideToggle(); });
    $(".linkb").bind("click", function() { $(".BOXB").slideToggle(); });
});

Comment: No in that case I would assign a specific class to the divs that will trigger the sliding. http://jsfiddle.net/Lkqdr/

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".linka").bind("click", function() {
        $(".BOXB").slideToggle();
        $(".BOXA").hide();
    });
    $(".linkb").bind("click", function() {
        $(".BOXA").slideToggle();
        $(".BOXB").hide();
    });
});`

Comment: I see your point. The problem I see is that this does not cater for more divs ... say you add another div you would have to add more code. Can you explain further?

Comment: you've taken my words .. 

this does not work for multiple divs .
I have 6 divs, square divs with a small read more button .
when I click the button/link I want to slide over another div with more info and a link on it to hide it .
that is what I want >

thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bhkcb/ ... it's not ready yet I will continue it later ... maybe u want to have look. It's getting a bit complicated hehe

Comment: wow thanks man .. i came up with this short code : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hJwqs/3/) . the problem is that they all work, and I would need them to work one by one ...

Wow, look at gary's method, please :) : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/cuEUG/)

Comment: I belive I have cracked it :) http://jsfiddle.net/8sugP/ Let me know what you think :)

Comment: hey man, thanks, looks very nice for an accordeation script, like a FAQ or something, but Gary gave a great answer for my problem . thanks anyway !